# Como debo interpretar un diseño web de photoshop para maquetarlo con html y css

Tags: css, html5

estoy tratando de aprender a maquetar usando pixel perfect, me propuse maquetar un diseño web hecho en psd, tiene lineas guias y las capas están divididas, entre otras, Segun yo las lineas guias representan a las columnas que puedo hacer al momento de maquetar el diseño. La verdad no se como interpretarlas  por lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según yo son 12 columnas, entre las columnas(los rectángulos color moradito)
hay como un espacio pero no se que significa, porque hay contenido dentro de esa sección de espacio, por ejemplo el logotipo del header se sale parcialmente de la columna 1 quedando parte de este en ese espacio entre las columnas

No entiendo...significa un padding derecho por columna o un margen y ignoro el hecho de que parte del contenido se sale de las columnas y solo me encargo de hacer que la separación entre columnas sea del mismo tamaño que en el diseño, y dejo todo el contenido dentro de la columna en si? y que hay del espacio que hay a la izquierda (al comienzo de las columnas) y a la derecha (al final de las columnas)? debo crear un margin izquierdo y derecho que tenga la misma distancia que en el diseño? en esos dos lados?

Agradecería que me ayudaran a editar mi pregunta si no me explique muy bien

Comment: tu maquetación está súper bien, pero encuentro que te estás enredando un poco, necesitas estudiar primero lo que es un sistema de grillas en css usando html ve este [link](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2018/01/30/maquetacion-con-css-grid/), esto te va a dar un poco la base para poder maquetar tu página de photoshop a un diseño web. Cuando tengas esto claro puedes usar una herramienta que se llama [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/), con la cual puedes hacer de forma más "profesional" tu página web. saludos y cualquier cosa, consulta nomas

Comment: No todo el contenido de tu maqueteo se acoge al sistema de encolumnado de Bootstrap. De ejemplo, aunque podrían estar en el mismo tipo de contenedor, la distribución de elementos de la barra de navegación, es distinta de la de tu cuerpo. @SebastiánMiranda puso por ahí un link a la documentación de Bootstrap 4, y cuando la veas te vas a dar cuenta de ello.

Comment: Cuando tu tienes un background de ese estilo puedes o hacer una imagen o utilizar un gradient (por ejemplo ```repeating-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(79,79,79,1) 0%, rgba(79,79,79,1) 5%, rgba(127,15,255,1) 5%, rgba(127,15,255,1) 10%)```). Y en cuanto a como se hace para que se vea por encima utilizas ```opacity``` o un ```rgba``` como background. De esa forma se ve el background general un poquito

Comment: Básicamente, estabas planteando mal el diseño. no hay 12 columnas, sino que hay un fondo que tiene 12 columnas y el contenido esta por encima de el (teniendo como ya he dicho los colores un ```opacity``` para ver dicho fondo a lineas)